# The if-statement gives me weird result in SwiftUI

Tags: if-statement, swiftui, tabview, appstorage

When I want to switch views between `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` using the buttons, it works but I am sent to the `Main` view first.

I tried using a `String` variable instead of `Bool`, replacing `@AppStorage` with a simple `@State/@Binding` and also specifying `@ViewBuilder` above `var body: some View` but nothing worked.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("firstView") var firstView = true
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            MainView()
            if firstView {
                ChildOneView()
            } else {
                ChildTwoView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonsView: View {
    @AppStorage("firstView") var firstView = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show ChildOne", action: { firstView = true })
            Button("Show ChildTwo", action: { firstView = false })
        }
    }
}

struct ChildOneView: View { // And also ChildTwoView
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ButtonsView()
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea why?

Comment: `TabView` will always default to the first view listed if you're not managing its selected state, which is why you're shown `MainView` first. You need to assign a tag value to each page view of the tab, and then give your tab view a state variable (either `@State`, or persisted using `@SceneStorage` which is a better fit than `@AppStorage`) that can retain and track the visible page. See https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/creating-tabs-with-tabview-and-tabitem for examples.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't want to switch between tabs but between views inside one tab. I could hack this issue with another view of type `@ViewBuilder` but I wanted something more clean.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem there is that you are not marking the views as tabItems in the TabView, instead you are just placing the views there and SwiftUI by default selects the first one, in your case `MainView()`. To solve it you just need to add the modifier `.tabItem {}` to each view and inside the braces set a label with the title and the image that you want to use in the tab.

```
MainView()
  .tabItem {
    Label("tab name", systemImage: "sfsymbolsImage")
  }

if firstView {
  ChildOneView()
    .tabItem {
      Label("tab name", systemImage: "sfsymbolsImage")
    }
} else {
    ChildTwoView()
      .tabItem {
        Label("tab name", systemImage: "sfsymbolsImage")
      }
}
```

This would be the solution, placing .tabItem in each view to mark them as tabItems, by default SwiftUI does not know that the views that you are placing in the tabView are tabItems, you need to say to SwiftUI that that views are tabItems and also, you are getting into the MainView because it is the one that is placed first, if you place first any other view you will go to that view.

Comment: Actually, I already have `.tabItem` for every views in my code. I just wanted to reduce it as much as possible for the sharing.